# Error when trying to create a file based unique hit counter on PHP

Tags: php

I'm learning to code in PHP by watching some youtube tutorials called "Beginner php tutorials" from the new Boston (maybe you know the channel). I was trying to create a unique hit counter using PHP but for some reason my code won't work. I hope you can help me out.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function hit_counter() {
    $ip_address=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo $ip_address;
    $ip_file=file('ip.txt');

    foreach ($ip_file as $ip) {
        $ip_single= trim($ip);
        if (@$ip_address!=$ip_single) {
            $ip_value=false;
            break;
        } else {
            $ip_value=true;    
        }
    }

    if (@ip_value==false) {
        $filename='count.txt';
        $handle=fopen($filename, 'r');
        $current=fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);

        $count=$current+1;

        $handle=fopen($filename, 'w');
        fwrite($filename, $count);
        fclose($handle);

        $handle=fopen('ip.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($ip_file, @$ip_address.'\n');
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What does won't work mean? Is an error or exception being thrown? Or does the code not do what you intended for it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not tested but it looks like the function could be simplified somewhat

```
function hit_counter() {
    /* sourcefile containing ips of visitors */
    $file=__DIR__ . '/ip.txt';

    /* get the user's ip address */
    $ip=trim( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );

    /* read contents of sourcefile into an array */
    $ips=file( $file );

    /* remove blank spaces from string */
    array_walk( $ips, function( &$v, $k ){ $v=trim( $v ); } );

    /* establish baseline count of unique ips */
    $count=count( $ips );

    /* Add new entry to file if not found & increment count */
    if( !in_array( $ip, $ips ) ){
        file_put_contents( $file, $ip . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
        $count++;
    }

    /* return the count for further processing */
    return $count;
}


$hits=hit_counter();
echo "Hits:{$hits}";
```

Comment: Sorry to answer late, i'll check the code and include the new commands you wrote :)), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've written a fuction, but it is not being invoked.

```
function doSomething(){
  ... execute code here ...
}

// Invoke function
doSomething();
```